# Update price without refresh the page

Tags: magento2, price, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am working on magento2 customization calculation functionality.
In this i have width and gather two field is there in text field 
I have to calculation with product price eg. price*width*gather like that.
That i did successfully but problem is in magento 1 we use to update price use **reloadPrice()** function is use but in magento 2 which function are require for update a final price

Answer (score 0):

before you call the new updated price html block make sure you reload the price block or price info by calling below code

```
$product->reloadPriceInfo();
```

that is

```
$product->setSpecialPrice(40); //you modified ant price  
$product->reloadPriceInfo(); //reload the price info
$this->getProductPrice($product); //display the price block
```

[How to reload the price programmatically in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204270/how-to-reload-the-price-programmatically-in-magento-2/204271)

if it works accept the answer i helps others