# How to reload the price programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price

i magento 2 in product view page based on some condition or input my SpecialPrice will be changed

so i follow below code in Block file but it return the old SpecialPrice , how to fix this issue

```
echo $block->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
echo $this->getCustomProductPrice($product);
```

in block

```
public function getCustomProductPrice(){
  $product->setSpecialPrice(40); 
  return $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
}
```

but it show old price only

Answer (score 1):

in Magento 2 when ever product object is loaded, It **init** the new object called  pricing info based on the price pool price will be displayed

so while product object is init and in  between price is changed it wont reflect till you reload it

**To reload the**

```
$product->reloadPriceInfo();
```

that is

```
public function getCustomProductPrice(){
  $product->setSpecialPrice(40); 
  $product->reloadPriceInfo();
  return $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
}
```